# How to run GitLab CI build on MR?

Tags: gitlab

I am new to GitLab CI, trying to setup a build that I need to be triggered when a merge request is created. Currently the build runs after the MR is accepted and merged into 'develop' branch. Which is good. But I was also expecting the build to run when a MR is created.

My gitlab-ci.yml is as follows - am I missing something?

```
stages:
  - test

test_project:
  stage: test
  script:
    - xcodebuild -scheme CodeRedTests -sdk iphonesimulator10.2 -workspace CodeRed.xcworkspace -configuration Debug clean build test -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,OS=10.2,name=iPhone 5s" | xcpretty -s
  only:
    - develop
  tags:
    - ios_10
    - xcode_8
    - osx_10-12
```

Answer (score 5):

Running tests when MR is created has been [hot topic](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/4176) since 2015 or even longer. **To be precise**, the need is to run tests on the merged code (from your branch to develop) in some pipeline. If everything is all right, then MR gets the green light.

Right now it's not available **yet**. A [doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/gitlab_flow.html#testing-before-merging) says:

> In old workflows the Continuous Integration (CI) server commonly ran
>   tests on the master branch only. Developers had to ensure their code
>   did not break the master branch. When using GitLab flow developers
>   create their branches from this master branch so it is essential it is
>   green. Therefore each merge request must be tested before it is
>   accepted. CI software like Travis and GitLab CI show the build results
>   right in the merge request itself to make this easy. One drawback is
>   that they are testing the feature branch itself and not the merged
>   result. What one can do to improve this is to test the merged result
>   itself. The problem is that the merge result changes every time
>   something is merged into master. Retesting on every commit to master
>   is computationally expensive and means you are more frequently waiting
>   for test results. **If there are no merge conflicts and the feature
>   branches are short lived the risk is acceptable. If there are merge
>   conflicts you merge the master branch into the feature branch and the
>   CI server will rerun the tests.** If you have long lived feature
>   branches that last for more than a few days you should make your
>   issues smaller.

So you can try to merge develop to your feature branch to ensure everything is ok, but you have to remove `only: develop` restriction.

Comment: Thank you Piotr for your time. According to GitLab doc it sounds achieve able ... Testing before merging (Please check the following links, any idea?)
https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/workflow/gitlab_flow.html
https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/workflow/ci_mr.png

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, we are looking at the same Doc! So it's not possible yet!?! Any idea when it will be available? :)

Comment: @AvishekDas No idea, right now it has `feature proposal` label and it's located in the backlog. We must observe.

Comment: Hopefully I'm understanding the issue correctly, but it seems like it should be available now since 11.6! https://about.gitlab.com/2018/12/22/gitlab-11-6-released/#run-cicd-for-merge-requests